# How do i create a queue output binding using C#

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For starters,  I'm using Visual Studio, not the Azure Functions portal. I found documentation that covers creating a queue output binding using the portal but can't find a way to apply this to plain old C# code.

I have a trigger wired up and functioning as-designed. Now, I want to add a message (string) to queue storage. How do I add the queue output binding and wire it up to the correct queue using C# in Visual Studio 2017.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you did in the scripts, but decorate it with `Queue` attribute, for instance

```cs
[return: Queue("MyQueue")]
public static string Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
```

or

```cs
public static string Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, 
    [Queue("MyQueue")] out MyMessage message)
```